# imagesx() not working for images outside current directory

Tags: php, image, upload

I am trying to upload an image using [Jarrod's](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/image-resizing-made-easy-with-php--net-10362) resize code.
The issue i'm facing is the images get resized perfectly while uploading images from the same folder. However, when i chose images from anywhere else, it shows a set of warnings. I know this could be a silly path issue but i'm unable to rectify it. Please help!!

The code for uploading on HTML is:

```
   <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="index.php" method="post">
    <input type="file" name="image" />
    <input type="submit" />
   </form>
```

The resize code on index.php is:

```
 <?php
  include_once("resize-class.php");
  $fileVal1 =   $_FILES['image']['name'];
  $resizeObj = new resize($fileVal1);
  $resizeObj -> resizeImage(500, 300, 'portrait');
  $resizeObj -> saveImage('sample-resized.gif', 100);
 ?>
```

The class file for resize-class.php is on the link above. Please help!
The warnings that appear are:

```
 Warning: imagesx() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\mgme-cms\resize\resize_class.php on line 17

 Warning: imagesy() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\mgme-cms\resize\resize_class.php on line 18

 Warning: Division by zero in C:\xampp\htdocs\mgme-cms\resize\resize_class.php on line 106

 Warning: imagecreatetruecolor() [function.imagecreatetruecolor]: Invalid image dimensions in C:\xampp\htdocs\mgme-cms\resize\resize_class.php on line 59

 Warning: imagecopyresampled() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\mgme-cms\resize\resize_class.php on line 60

 Warning: imagegif() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\mgme-cms\resize\resize_class.php on line 206

 Warning: imagedestroy() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\mgme-cms\resize\resize_class.php on line 229
```

Comment: your form code inside `index.php` file??

Comment: No - form is on form.php . Action page is index.php

Comment: `$resizeObj = new resize('$fileVal1');` change this

Comment: no that would be incorrect

Comment: `$resizeObj -> resizeImage(500, 300, 'crop');` in here

Comment: no the issue comes in right in the beginning.